# Length of column when in reaches a certain value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to  to take the length of the column when the Time column reaches the 5 minutes( the seconds are  not  important). For example when time reaches 5 the length
of the column  is 436 in this file . The Time column is type object. There are multiple files and I cant do this manually for each one. Here is a sample from the txt files that I imported in my project.

```
Time    Sample #  
0:00.050       18     
0:00.308      111    
0:00.953      343    
0:01.586      571    
0:02.242      807     
0:02.911     1048     
0:03.575     1287     
0:04.231     1523     
0:04.903     1765     
0:05.539     1994     
0:06.164     2219    
0:06.764     2435    
0:07.392     2661
```

Comment: Where did `436` come from? I didn't get it..

Comment: maybe you can loop through it and sum it, when sum = 5min then check index, and reset sum = 0 and continue

Comment: It was an example for what the length of the column is in a particular txt file when it reaches the 5 minutes. I should have given a more complete picture you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already a Dataframe composed of the table you showed, with two columns ('Time' and 'Sample'):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# function to convert string into datetime, if 'Time' is not in datetime format yet
str_dt = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%M:%S.%f')
df.Time = df.Time.apply(lambda x: str_dt(x))
# set column 'Time' as index
df = df.set_index('Time')

# get the minute for each index entry
idx_minute = lambda x: x.minute

# find the position of all entries when reading 5 minutes
length_5_minute = np.where(df.apply(lambda x: idx_minute(x.index)) == 5)[0]

# The position of the first entry when reahing 5 minutes
length_5_minute = length_5_minute[0]\
                    if len(length_5_minute) > 0\
                    else []
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Even thought i am not familiar with some of the code it works for me. I tested it and got close to what i  originally wanted. The size of the column  was always matched  at  4.59 min but with  adding  +2 to the length_5_minute fixed it. Thank you again

Comment: You're welcome! If you need any explanation just let me know.

The reason why you need to add 2 may be due to two things:
- The indexes in Python start at 0, not 1. So, when we find the index of a certain value in an array, we need to take into consideration that the index started at 0, not at 1. So we need to add 1.
- The columns' titles also need to be considered, so that is why you need to add this extra 1.

Let me know if you need any further help. Good luck.

In total, you need to add 1 + 1 = 2.